# Why is the "then" property automatically accessed on an object returned from an async function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

When an object is returned from an asynchronous function something automatically accesses the .then property of that object. Why does this happen?

```js
//Use a proxy to monitor property access of an object, warn if property accessed is "then"
const createProxiedPerson = person => new Proxy(person, {
  get: function(target, property, receiver) {
    const value = Reflect.get(target, property, receiver)
    if (property === "then") console.log({ target, property, receiver })
    return value
  }
})

const getPersonAfterLoadingVideos = async person => {
  //person.videos = await fetch.....
  return createProxiedPerson(person)
}

getPersonAfterLoadingVideos({ name: "Bill", videoCategory: "funny cats", age: 45 })
```

Comment: `Promise.resolve(createProxiedPerson(person))` (or more closely, `new Promise(resolve => { …; resolve(createProxiedPerson(person)); })`) does.

Comment: @Aplet123 hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with JS's promise flattening behavior. Since sometimes people return a promise from their async functions, the async function itself essentially unwraps promise layers when returning the value [by calling `Promise.resolve` on it](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-async-functions-abstract-operations-async-function-start). [`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) will call `.then` when the argument is a thenable.

Answer (score 0):

An async function is a sugar syntax for a JS `Promise`. Let's understand this fragment:

```js
const asyncDuplicate = (n) => Promise.resolve(2 * n)

const asyncDuplicateOddIntegers = (n) => {
  if(n % 2 == 0) {
    return asyncDuplicate(n) // This returns a promise
  } else {
    return n // this does returns a value
  }
}
```

A function can return a value or a promise, but when the function is called with a `.then()`, the method receive always a value:

```
// Here n is not a Promise, but also a value equal to 4
asyncDuplicateOddIntegers(2).then(n => console.log(n))

// Here n is a value equal to 3
asyncDuplicateOddIntegers(2).then(n => console.log(n))
```

This is because to receive a `Promise` is useless. Then, let's rewrite the `asyncDuplicate` functions with async/await:

```js
const asyncDuplicate = async (n) => 2 * n
```

And the `asyncDuplicateOddIntegers` function can continue being the same or be rewritten as follows:

```js
const asyncDuplicateOddIntegers = async (n) => {
  if(n % 2 == 0) {
    return asyncDuplicate(n) // This returns a promise
  } else {
    return n // this does returns a value
  }
}
```

But using `await` with `asyncDuplicate`:

```js
const asyncDuplicateOddIntegers = async (n) => {
  if(n % 2 == 0) {
    return await asyncDuplicate(n) // This returns a value
  } else {
    return n // this does returns a value
  }
}
```

This probe that an `async` function calls the `.then()` method **if exists** (if an object has a `.then()` method it is a `thenable` object).

But how it can know if a variable is a simple value or a `Promise`?

```js
const a = 1
a.then // undefined

Promise.resolve(1).then // This is a function/method (different to undefined)
```

Now, let's talk about Proxy:
Every time an attribute or method is called, this will run the getter. This getters return some proxy person but before returning the non-thenable value, if the property/method called is `.then`, it will call to `console.log({ target, property, receiver })`

With these two point of views, we know that every `async` function calls to `.then` to verify if is a promise despite the fact that the proxy person isn't.
Next, the `createProxiedPerson` function will return a `Promise.resolve(someProxyPerson) and in the process (before returns the` Promise) will call to the `console.log({ target, property, receiver })` sentence.

Comment: Thanks Frank, the proxy was used to explain the situation without having to write any words. @Aplet123's answer is far more succinct.

Comment: @BlueWater86 if the question only were about `.then` invocation, that answer would be enough, but the proxy does not have a `.then` and the `console.log({ target, property, receiver })` is invoked.

Then, in this case, the `async` function isn't unwrapping the .`then()` method because it doesn't exist. That's why I explained all the process.

Comment: It was only about .then invocation.